# Búsqueda secuencial en C

Tags: c, codeblocks

Estoy realizando un algoritmo por el cual ingreso 5 números y después ingreso un numero para verificar si el mismo se encuentra o no en el arreglo, la cuestión es que probé con un while sin bandera y no funciono, ahora pruebo con un while con bandera y tampoco, siempre me tira el resultado en falso y no logro localizar el error.

```
int carga() {
  int p[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("ingrese el numero positivo %d: ", i + 1);
    scanf("%d", & p[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}

int busqueda(int p[]) {
  int numero, i;
  char band = 'F';
  i = 0;
  printf("ingrese un numero para buscar en el arreglo: ");
  scanf("%d", & numero);
  while ((band == 'F') && (i < 5)) {
    if (p[i] == numero) {
      band = 'V';
    }
    i++;
  }
  if (band == 'F') {
    printf("el numero no existe en el arreglo");
  } else {
    if (band == 'V') {
      printf("el numero fue encontrado en la posicion: %d", i - 1);
    }
  }

  return 0;

}
int main() {
  int p[5];
  carga();
  busqueda(p);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cuando cargas los datos no los cargas a al `p` que tienes en main, sino a una
variable local que tienes en la funcion `carga`.

Comment: como podria invocar lo que cargue en el arreglo p  en la funcion carga? porque me piden que lo realice de esa manera

Comment: Si tu código refleja correctamente lo que te están
pidiendo, entonces lo que  te están pidiendo no
tiene sentido. Que tal si editas tu pregunta para
incluir lo que te están pidiendo?